# Samba/Monterey: Cannot open files inside folder after rename

Tags: macos, finder, smb, monterey

Symptom: I mount a SMB share via finder, rename a folder and after that i cannot open any files inside this folder anymore. there's no error message, just nothing happens after double-clicking on file. Seems like a bug in finder. Anyone else experiencing this? It makes samba quite unuseable.

- the folder definitely gets renamed on the server, i verified that.
- it works under big sur or older (and did for years now)
- when i force-quit finder and navigate to the renamed folder again i can open the files.
- it works when i navigate via terminal to the renamed location and open files via terminal.
- dir_cache_max_cnt=0 in nsmb.conf does not help
- samba server is configured properly (debian buster). i tried to disable any fruit extensions and several min/max protocol options. nothing helped.

Comment: Has anyone figured a permanent solution to this? I am having this issue and am baffled. I theorize it has something to do with Gatekeeper or the Quarantine flag for malware. And the OS is being overly protective due to a file being moved or renamed being “suspicious”

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the cloud app or relaunching Finder works as a temporary workaround but I don't think there's a permanent fix for this.

I see the same results here but with cloud provider mounted drive using macFUSE. I have attempted this on other macOS versions and things work as expected. The issue occurs only on Monterey (both Intel and M1).